# Python pandas resample added dates not present in the original data

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to convert intraday data, stored in `data_m`, to daily data. For some reason `resample` added rows for days that were not present in the intraday data. For example, 1/8/2000 is not in the intraday data, yet the daily data contains a row for that date with NaN as the value. DatetimeIndex has more entries than the actual data. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
data_m.resample('D', how = mean).head()
Out[13]: 
           x
2000-01-04 8803.879581
2000-01-05 8765.036649
2000-01-06 8893.156250
2000-01-07 8780.037433
2000-01-08 NaN

data_m.resample('D', how = mean)
Out[14]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 4729 entries, 2000-01-04 00:00:00 to 2012-12-14 00:00:00
Freq: D
Data columns:
x    3241  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing looks correct, it's just that pandas gives NaN for the mean of an empty array.

```
In [1]: Series().mean()
Out[1]: nan
```

[`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample) converts to a **regular** time interval, so if there are no samples that day you get NaN.

Most of the time having NaN isn't a problem. If it is we can either use `fill_method` (for example `'ffill'`) or if you really wanted to remove them you could use `dropna` (not recommended):

```
data_m.resample('D', how = mean, fill_method='ffill')
data_m.resample('D', how = mean).dropna()
```

---

Update: The modern equivalent seems to be:

```
In [21]: s.resample("D").mean().ffill()
Out[21]:
                      x
2000-01-04  8803.879581
2000-01-05  8765.036649
2000-01-06  8893.156250
2000-01-07  8780.037433
2000-01-08  8780.037433

In [22]: s.resample("D").mean().dropna()
Out[22]:
                      x
2000-01-04  8803.879581
2000-01-05  8765.036649
2000-01-06  8893.156250
2000-01-07  8780.037433
```

See [resample docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Comment: dropna() on a resampled object does not seem to work anymore (pandas 0.23.4) any idea how to remove those pesky na rows?

Comment: @user189035 interesting, looks like `.resample('D').mean().ffill()` is the modern equivalent.

Comment: @user189035 or `.resample('D').mean().dropna()` to drop

Answer (score 1):

Prior to 0.10.0, pandas labeled resample bins with the right-most edge, which for daily resampling, is the next day.  Starting with 0.10.0, the default binning behavior for daily and higher frequencies changed to `label='left', closed='left'` to minimize this confusion.  See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#api-changes for more information.