# Resampling by mean in pandas with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with multiple columns at a 15 minute time step. This DataFrame contains some NaNs. I am taking the mean of all the columns and resampling to a daily time step. I expected these two commands to have the give the same output and at first I couldn't figure out why they didn't.

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=300, freq='15T')
data = {'a': np.random.rand(300), 'b': np.random.rand(300)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index)
df['a'][2:10] = np.nan

In [153]: df.mean(axis=1).resample('24H', how='mean')
Out[153]:
         2000-01-01    0.503772
         2000-01-02    0.502624
         2000-01-03    0.473651
         2000-01-04    0.366844
         Freq: 24H, dtype: float64

In [154]: df.resample('24H', how='mean').mean(axis=1)
Out[154]:
         2000-01-01    0.509912
         2000-01-02    0.502624
         2000-01-03    0.473651
         2000-01-04    0.366844
         Freq: 24H, dtype: float64
```

I realized that given the NaNs in my data, the order in which the operations happen really does matter. If I take the mean across my columns first and resample second, then the columns with values will be weighted. If I resample first and then take the mean across columns, then certain timesteps will be weighted (for example: if there is only one value for a whole day that will be taken as the mean of that day). I can't think of a way around this unfair weighting.

Comment: Upsampling will introduce `NaN` values this is expected operation

Comment: @EdChum I did not get `NaN`s if there were any values in the day

Comment: @js-0405 That is just math. It is the way your are averaging. Average of averages depends on the order because although multiplication and addition are associative on their own, together they are not. There is no way to avoid getting different results, unless all your values are exactly the same.

Comment: I was thinking of melting my dataframes and then averaging but it takes way too long.

Comment: sup, moneygrip. try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984461/python-pandas-resample-added-dates-not-present-in-the-original-data